# Como hacer que la imagen principal ocupe el 100% de anchura y altura

Tags: html, css3

Quisiera saber como hacer para que la imagen principal de una página tenga un alto del 100% del navegador principalmente sin necesidad de aplicarle píxeles.

Lo logro hacer aplicandole los píxeles pero al momento de verlo desde otra pc o un monitor con resoluciones diferentes de pantalla este ya no se ve igual ya que este lo tenia predefinido para una resolucion específica.

Quiero lograr algo como esto [Ver Aqui](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/obliguepersonal-template/full_screen_preview/21641486?_ga=2.153691824.922617626.1529637166-1808112208.1528433311), que como se puede ver cuando se abre la pagina hay una imagen principal y si se ve desde otro dispositivo se sigue viendo lo mismo sin ninguna distorsión o que la imagen se vea cortada. Ojo, la pagina no es mia solo la pongo como ejemplo.

Mi codigo:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura');
body {
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html{
 height: 100%;
}
.contenedor{
 background: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-R1WaUskJr_s/TrxJoBiea9I/AAAAAAAAAVU/JAUoAJTDNY8/s1600/fondo+pantalla.jpg) no-repeat center ;
 height: 844px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  <!--Content  E IMAGEN PRINCIAL-->
  <div class="contenedor d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <h1>Titulo</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS cuenta con un conjunto de propiedades que hacen exactamente lo que buscas

`background-size:cover` hace  que la imagen se aplique a todo el contenedor sin mostrar los sobrantes a los lados o arriba y abajo

`background-position: center center` hace que el origen de la imagen sea el centro vertical y horizontal

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura');
body {
 height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html{
 height: 100%;
}
.contenedor{
 background: url(https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-R1WaUskJr_s/TrxJoBiea9I/AAAAAAAAAVU/JAUoAJTDNY8/s1600/fondo+pantalla.jpg) no-repeat center ;
   height: 100%;
     background-size:     cover;                      /* <------ */
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  <!--Content  E IMAGEN PRINCIAL-->
  <div class="contenedor d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <h1>Titulo</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

si a un div le aplicas este codigo:

```css
height: 100vh;

width: 100vh;
```

Debería darte la altura y anchura de la pagina en ese momento, igualmente si le colocas una imagen de fondo al div puedes poner:

```css
background-size: cover;
```